# Disable DELETE for PostGIS Role/USER yet allowing them To INSERT new Features?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I intent to block my USERS from deleting features on PostGIS Database. I disabled DELETE in pgAdmin as below but the USERS are now unable to save feature on the database using QGIS3 as client. On trying to save any changes in QGIS it give  **Commit Errors: Could not commit changes to Layer...**

*How then do I stop users from DELETING features yet giving them privileges of ADDING NEW features?*

[image: Unchecked DELETE privilege in pgAdmin4]